# beautiful soup find all not finding div

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am downloading some Spanish verbs & their conjugations to improve my Spanish.

On the web page ([link here](https://www.linguasorb.com/spanish/verbs/conjugation/trabajar)) under the verb at the top their is the English translation. However using the code below is not working, I'm not sure why though? It returns None, why, I can see it on the web page?

```
URL = 'https://www.linguasorb.com/spanish/verbs/conjugation/trabajar
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
res = soup.find_all('div', class_='l1-infinitive')
```

Comment: Works [here](https://repl.it/@JustinEzequiel/bs4TanSvelteProfile). Print out `page.content` so we see what you are getting back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with this code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

URL = 'https://www.linguasorb.com/spanish/verbs/conjugation/trabajar'

page = requests.get(URL)
soup = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')
res = soup.find_all('div', class_='l1-infinitive')
print(res)
```

Outputs
`[<div class="l1-infinitive">to work</div>]` on my machine.

## Edit: a few more details about what `res` is

`res` is an instance of `bs4.element.ResultSet`. You can manipulate it like a list, thanks to duck typing.

`res[0]` is an instance of `bs4.element.Tag`.
`print(res[0])` outputs a string representing the tag and its contents, because of how the `Tag` class implements the `__str__` method.

BeautifulSoup gives you various possibilities to extract strings from a `Tag` elements. In this particular case, `res[0].text` returns the string `"to work"`, which I think is what's you're looking for.

`res[0].string` returns an instance of `bs4.element.NavigableString`. [More info about them](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring) in the docs.

Comment: Ah yes when I print(res) I'm getting the same. For other pages I was doing res[0].text to get the english translation. What is the best way to get 'to work' from the res element?

Comment: This is a correct way to extract string content. I've edited my answer.
I suspect res returning `None` was due to a network error of some kind.